# How to remove years in csv chart

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, datetime, matplotlib

I write a python program to convert csv files into charts.
It shows 1900 in the chart but I don't need it.
Please help me check where is the problem.
Thanks.

```
import csv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
filename='/home/pi/env_watcher/temp/env_report.csv'
with open(filename) as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f)
    header_row=next(reader)
    dates,ttemps,ctemps,thumis,chumis=[],[],[],[],[]
    for row in reader:
        current_date=datetime.strptime(row[0],'%b %d %H:%M:%S')
        dates.append(current_date)
        ttemp=float(row[1])
        ttemps.append(ttemp)
        ctemp=float(row[2])
        ctemps.append(ctemp)
        thumi=float(row[3])
        thumis.append(thumi)
        chumi=float(row[4])
        chumis.append(chumi)

fig=plt.figure(dpi=128,figsize=(10,6))
plt.plot(dates,thumis,c='red',alpha=0.5)
plt.plot(dates,chumis,c='blue',alpha=0.5)
plt.title('Weekly Humidity',fontsize=24)
plt.xlabel('',fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('Humidity(%)',fontsize=16)
plt.tick_params(axis='both',which='major',labelsize=16)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.savefig("/home/pi/env_watcher/temp/env_humi.png")
plt.show()
```

csv file content is as follows
......
Aug 25 05:10:13,30,26.8,70,45.0
Aug 25 05:20:13,30,26.8,70,44.8
Aug 25 05:30:15,30,26.8,70,45.5
Aug 25 05:40:13,30,26.8,70,45.5
Aug 25 05:50:13,30,26.9,70,46.1
Aug 25 06:00:13,30,26.9,70,46.3
Aug 25 06:10:13,30,26.9,70,46.8
Aug 25 06:20:13,30,26.9,70,46.8
......

Output:
[image]

Comment: This is my csv file.
Please try it, thanks.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZPYx4hRIIAPtlI3idYJKsgtGMASRnANa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use set_major_formatter() on xaxis to set date format as per your need:

```
import csv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

filename = '/home/pi/env_watcher/temp/env_report.csv'
with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header_row = next(reader)
    dates, ttemps, ctemps, thumis, chumis = [], [], [], [], []
    for row in reader:
        current_date = datetime.strptime(row[0], '%b %d %H:%M:%S')
        dates.append(current_date)
        ttemp = float(row[1])
        ttemps.append(ttemp)
        ctemp = float(row[2])
        ctemps.append(ctemp)
        thumi = float(row[3])
        thumis.append(thumi)
        chumi = float(row[4])
        chumis.append(chumi)

fig = plt.figure(dpi=128, figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(dates, thumis, c='red', alpha=0.5)
plt.plot(dates, chumis, c='blue', alpha=0.5)
plt.title('Weekly Humidity', fontsize=24)
plt.xlabel('', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('Humidity(%)', fontsize=16)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=16)
fig.axes[0].xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m-%d'))  # Won't show year
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.savefig("/home/pi/env_watcher/temp/env_humi.png")
plt.show()
```

Comment: The problem is sloved. Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you do not need the conversion here. Just use

```
for row in reader:
    current_date=row[0]
```

---

or if you just need date and month
**Use:**

```
current_date=datetime.strptime("Aug 25 05:10:13",'%b %d %H:%M:%S').strftime("%m-%d")
```

Comment: I modify code as below.  
....  
header_row=next(reader)  
dates,ttemps,ctemps,thumis,chumis=[],[],[],[],[]  
for row in reader:  
# current_date=datetime.strptime(row[0],'%b %d %H:%M:%S')  
current_date=row[0]  
dates.append(current_date)  
ttemp=float(row1)   
....  
And create a chart like this.  
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1J14uf-GcwfTUE48s79dsXIqTK-mlDMsQ  
The X axis is a bit crowded，is there a way to simplify it?